# iOS Video Recording - Only lets me take pictures

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller, recording

I have an app that I need to record videos. Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)takeVideo:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It works perfectly in other applications but in my current app it brings up the camera and there's no record button, only the image capture button. I've notice also that the iOS camera app loses the ability to record when this happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your picker and 
To designate all available media types for a source, use a statement like this:

> picker.cameraCaptureMode =
>   UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
>   picker.mediaTypes =
>       [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
>           UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

Comment: Didn't work, got this error, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'cameraCaptureMode 1 not available because mediaTypes does contain public.movie'". Strange cos I was able to log that public.movie was a media type.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and I found that if you make sure the AVAudioSession Category is Record it will allow you to record video. If it is not set to that it will default to the Still Photo Capturer

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord);
```

I subclassed UIImagePickerController and inside of LoadView set the category.